# How to Filter Rows in a DataFrame Based on a Specific Number of Characters and Numbers

Tags: python, regex, pandas

New Python user here, so please pardon my ignorance if my approach seems completely off.

I am having troubles filtering rows of a column based off of their Character/Number format.

Here's an example of the DataFrame and Series

```
df = {'a':[1,2,4,5,6], 'b':[7, 8, 9,10 ], 'target':[ 'ABC1234','ABC123', '123ABC', '7KZA23']
```

The column I am looking to filter is the "target" column based on their character/number combos and I am essentially trying to make a dict like below

```
{'ABC1234': counts_of_format
 'ABC123': counts_of_format
 '123ABC': counts_of_format
 'any_other_format': counts_of_format}
```

Here's my progress so far:

```
 col = df['target'].astype('string')
 abc1234_pat = '^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4]'
 matches = re.findall(abc1234_pat, col)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
    TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I've double checked the dtype and it comes back as string. I've researched the TypeError and the only solutions I can find it converting it to a string.

Any insight or suggestion on what I might be doing wrong, or if this is simply the wrong approach to this problem, will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need this: df.groupby('target').size().to_dict() [Here df is a dataframe not dict]

Comment: So, you have a list of patterns, and you want to check how many items in the `target` column match that pattern in full, right? Or do you need to also extract the matching values?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi Wiktor, thanks for response! Yeah, so essential the dataframe I am working with has around 80,000+ rows, and I am trying to create a dict that returns how many times the different character/number combos occur. For example, how many time does 3 characters followed by 4 numbers occur and so on.

Comment: @Muhammadhassan Hi Muhammad, thanks for the comment! The problem I am running into is that I need to account for the different character/number sequences. Can size help with that?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a dict that returns how many times the different character/number combos occur. For example, how many time does 3 characters followed by 4 numbers occur and so on.

(Your problem would have been earlier and easier understood had you stated this in the question post itself rather than in a comment.)

By *characters*, you mean letters; by *numbers*, you mean digits.

> ```
> abc1234_pat = '^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4]'
> ```

Since you want to count occurrences of all *character/number combos*, this approach of using one concrete pattern would not lead very far. I suggest to transform the targets to a canonical form which serves as the key of your desired *dict*, e. g. substitute every letter with `C` and every digit with `N` (using your terms).

Of the many ways to tackle this, one is using [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) together with a class which does the said transformation.

```
class classify():
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return ord('C' if chr(key).isalpha() else 'N' if chr(key).isdigit() else None)

occ = df.target.str.translate(classify()).value_counts()#.todict()
```

Note that this will purposely raise an exception if `target` contains non-alphanumeric characters.
You can convert the resulting Series to a *dict* with [`.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) if you like.